# Returning pdo fetch object from function

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

Hi I'm building php pdo function library, but I'm stuck at returning `fetchObject` to while loop parameter. When i'm trying to load the page, it just loads and loads, not printing any result. Oh yeah, my code:

functions.php

```
function pdo_run($query, $autoval = null, $values = null) {

global $stmt;
global $db;

$values = preg_match_all("~'([^']+)'~", $query, $matches);

$stmt = $db->prepare("$query");

if (!$autoval) {
    $stmt->execute($matches[0]);
}
else {
    $stmt->execute($values);
}

}

function pdo_result() {

global $stmt;

if ($stmt) {
        return '$stmt->fetchObject(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)';
}
else {
    trigger_error('generic ERROR: No pdo query found. Advanced info: global variable $stmt not found', E_USER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

test.php

```
pdo_run('SELECT * FROM settings');

while ($result = pdo_result()) {
  echo $result['setting'] . "<br />";
      echo $result['value'] . "<br />";
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks for help :)

Comment: this function makes absolutely no sense. You should never use it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yep i'm sorry i fixed it.

Comment: @Your Common Sense What's the problem in my function?

Comment: Not "problem" but way too much problems

Comment: Here's one problem: `return '$stmt->fetchObject(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)';` returns a string, not data from your database. The rest makes little sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found how to do that. I put `return $stmt;` to my query function, and then i added query parameter to my `pdo_result` function. Query function returns the statement, and i use it in result function. Code:

```
function pdo_result($query) {

$res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!isset($res)) {
    trigger_error('PDO generic ERROR: No pdo query found', E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    return $res;
}
}
```

Then i use it like this:

```
$query = pdo_run('SELECT * FROM settings');

while ($row = pdo_result($query)) {
echo $row['setting'] . ': ' . $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: This is extremely funny function :) You just wrote a lot of code that would never execute, while the only meaningful part is just a synonym call of PDO statement fetch. So, you better change `while ($row = pdo_result($query)) {` to `while ($row = $query->fetch())) {` - at least it will make code sensible.

Comment: Well, you can do it just the way you like, i don't see any reason why i shouldn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the one of possible ways to implement such a function. You must return statement, not make it global. And of course you should avoid that awful autoval magic.

```
function pdo_run($query, $values = null)
{
    global $db; // it could be questioned too, but let it be someone else
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($values);
    return $stmt;
}
$stmt = pdo_run('SELECT * FROM settings');
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo $row['setting'] . ": ";
    echo $row['value']   . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Any way to do it with while loop?

Comment: yes you can do it in while loop as well. though I've no idea why would you want one

Comment: it's the same while as in any other example. I've no idea why you're demanding a personal one. Anyway, not until you explain why do you want only while and nothing else

Comment: This part: `return $stmt;` saved me day :) +1